Having i18next-conv ignore underscores except for _one and _other
If we have some JSON like this:
{
  "welcome": {
    "title": "hello",
    "hello_world": "yay",
    "sample_one": "{{count}} shoe",
    "sample_other": "{{count}} shoes"
  },
  "soil": {
    "bedrock": "Bedrock",
    "rock_fragment": {
      "VOLUME_0_1": "0–1%",
      "VOLUME_1_60": "35–60%",
      "VOLUME_60": ">60%"
    }
  }
}

It converts to PO like this:
msgctxt "0"
msgid "soil##rock##VOLUME"
msgstr "0–1%"

msgctxt "1"
msgid "soil##rock##VOLUME"
msgid_plural "soil##rock##VOLUME"
msgstr[0] ""
msgstr[1] "35–60%"

msgid "welcome##title"
msgstr "hello"

msgid "soil##bedrock"
msgstr "Bedrock"

msgid "soil##rock##VOLUME"
msgid_plural "soil##rock##VOLUME"
msgstr[0] ""
msgstr[1] ">60%"

msgctxt "world"
msgid "welcome##hello"
msgstr "yay"

msgctxt "one"
msgid "welcome##sample"
msgstr "{{count}} shoe"

msgctxt "other"
msgid "welcome##sample"
msgstr "{{count}} shoes"

Using a command like so:
i18next-conv i18next-conv  -l en -s en.json -t en.po

Is there a way to have only keys ending in _one and _other are treated as plurals?
Resulting in something like this?
msgid "soil##rock_fragment##VOLUME_0_1"
msgstr "0–1%"

msgid "soil##rock_fragment##VOLUME_35_60"
msgstr[1] "35–60%"

msgid "soil##rock_fragment##VOLUME_60"
msgstr[1] ">60%"

msgid "welcome##title"
msgstr "hello"

msgid "soil##bedrock"
msgstr "Bedrock"

msgid "welcome##hello_world"
msgstr "yay"

msgctxt "one"
msgid "welcome##sample"
msgstr "{{count}} shoe"

msgctxt "other"
msgid "welcome##sample"
msgstr "{{count}} shoes"

